# Debugger: "cannot open file: malloc.c"

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I'm coding a hash game in C and I'm using `malloc` to alocate the memory for the table. However, when I compile the program, I get a segmentation fault. Using the debugger I was able to find an error: apparently, I can't use malloc because it can't find the malloc.c or something like this. Here is the code (where the segfault occurs):

```
int inicializaTabuleiro(char *ptrTabuleiro)
{
    //Aloca memória para o tabuleiro
    ptrTabuleiro = malloc(9);

    //Verifica se a memória foi alocada
    if(!ptrTabuleiro)
        return 0;

    int contadorPosicao;

    //Preenche o tabuleiro com '-'
    for(contadorPosicao = 0; contadorPosicao < 9; contadorPosicao++)
            ptrTabuleiro[contadorPosicao] = '-';

    return 1;
}
```

Any thoughts on what may be causing it? Additional info: using codeblocks with GCC compiler on Linux Mint. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Trust me, you don't need to look at malloc.c; the bug isn't there. It's earlier in your code, when you wrote out of bounds of an array.

Comment: You're probably trying to step into the `malloc` source code, and the debugger doesn't know where that is. Rest assured, your segfault is not being caused by problematic code in malloc.c .. it's your code causing the segfault. Just step over the call to malloc in `gdb` with "next" or "n" (not "step" or "s"). If it's crashing at the `malloc` line, you probably have some undefined behavior before you get there.

Comment: just let gdb run the code, it will break where the segfault is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not inside your code snippet, which is fine, mostly. The problem is that you are not returning the pointer to the caller! In C parameters are passed by value, so if you do something like:

```
char *arr;
mycharalloc(arr);
arr[3] = 'X'; /* <-- arr is still uninitialized! */
```

mycharalloc uses its local copy of arr to store the newly created pointer, but inside the caller arr is untouched. Hence, arr is a random pointer, and the next time you write something to it, you get segfault.

I would suggest changing your function to:

```
char *inicializaTabuleiro()
{
    //Aloca memória para o tabuleiro
    char *ptrTabuleiro = malloc(9);

    //Verifica se a memória foi alocada
    if(!ptrTabuleiro)
        return NULL;

    int contadorPosicao;

    //Preenche o tabuleiro com '-'
    for(contadorPosicao = 0; contadorPosicao < 9; contadorPosicao++)
            ptrTabuleiro[contadorPosicao] = '-';

    return ptrTabuleiro;
}
```

Then in the caller:

```
char *myTable = inicializaTabuleiro();
if (!myTable)
    error();
```

Comment: recommend `(void)` as the parameter list, which means no arguments.  Empty parentheses means unspecified number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly initializing something that will be used outside the function.  So you need one more level of indirection.  Change the pointer type to `char**`.

```
int inicializaTabuleiro(char **ptrTabuleiro)
{
    //Aloca memória para o tabuleiro
    *ptrTabuleiro = malloc(9);

    //Verifica se a memória foi alocada
    if(!*ptrTabuleiro)
        return 0;

    int contadorPosicao;

    //Preenche o tabuleiro com '-'
    for(contadorPosicao = 0; contadorPosicao < 9; contadorPosicao++)
            (*ptrTabuleiro)[contadorPosicao] = '-';

    return 1;
}
```

And call like this:

```
char *ptrTabuleiro;
if( inicializaTabuleiro( &ptrTabuleiro ) )
{
    /* now you can use ptrTabuleiro */
}
```